# Some problems with Bootstrap collapse + Tab navigation

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/p5sZJ/10/

Bug is reproduced **only in IE 10** (chrome, firefox works perfectly fine).
Bug is not reproduced in IE 9 because it doesn't support css transitions.
Bug is not reproduced in IE 11 and in IE 11 working in IE 10 mode.
**(see my last edit, this information is irrelevant)**

**Steps to reproduce a bug:**

1. Click on "Second" tab.
2. Click on "Heading" collapse.
3. Open inner-collapse by clicking on the "Inner-link".
4. Close inner-collapse by clicking on the "Inner-link" again.
5. Click on "First" tab.
6. Click on the "Link to open accordion".
7. Try to open-close inner-collapse and main collapse.

**Expected result:** the collapses open and close perfectly fine.
**Actual result:** the collapses dont work.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="mainTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
    <li><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="mainTabContent" class="tab-content" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id="first" class="tab-pane">
        <a id="anchor" ng-click="navigate()">Link to open accordion</a>
    </div>

    <div id="second" class="tab-pane">
        <div id="second-accordion" class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#second-body">
                    Heading
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="second-body" class="accordion-body collapse">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Table Head</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a id="anchor-inner" href="#second-inner" data-toggle="collapse">
                                    Inner link
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="collapse-row">
                            <td>
                                <div id="second-inner" class="collapse">
                                    <div class="inner-description">
                                        Description
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.navigate = function(){
        $('#mainTab li:eq(1) a').tab('show');

        var inner = $('#second-inner');

        if (!$(inner).parents('.collapse').hasClass('in')) {
            $(inner).parents('.collapse').collapse('show');
        }
        if (!$(inner).hasClass('in')) {
            $(inner).collapse('show');
        }
    };  
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var collapse = $('.collapse');

    collapse.on('hidden', function (event) {
        $(event.target).children().hide();
    });

    collapse.on('show', function (event) {
        $(event.target).children().show();
    });    
});
```

P.S. Seems like the bug is reproduced only when using AngularJs. **(see my last edit, this information is irrelevant)** Somehow in IE 10 the 'transitionend' event is not raised and that's why the collapses get stuck, but why is it not raised.

**Edit:**

Bug is reproduced without AngularJS and in all browsers. I've added comments to my answer. You can reproduce the bug by simply clicking on the tab (that has collapsed collapse-element in it) and then immediately clicking on the collapse header to expand. Try several times in the old jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping calls to collapse('show') in setTimeOut 0 worked in my case.

http://jsfiddle.net/p5sZJ/12/

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.navigate = function(){
        $('#mainTab li:eq(1) a').tab('show');

        var inner = $('#second-inner');

        setTimeOut(function(){
        if (!$(inner).parents('.collapse').hasClass('in')) {
            $(inner).parents('.collapse').collapse('show');
        }
        if (!$(inner).hasClass('in')) {
            $(inner).collapse('show');
        }}, 0);
    };  
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var collapse = $('.collapse');

    collapse.on('hidden', function (event) {
        $(event.target).children().hide();
    });

    collapse.on('show', function (event) {
        $(event.target).children().show();
    });    
});
```

**Edit:**

I have finally discovered the real source of the problem and why you should set the timeout to fix it. Apparently you should be very carefull when unhiding collapse elements and interacting with them immediately after that, cause transitionEnd event might not fire. You can find the details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions . So you better set a timeout of 20, instead of zero. Also, if the user opens the tab with the collapse and clicks on the collapse immediately it might break even in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bootstrap Ui 
http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
Its special library write to cooperate bootstrap with angular.

Comment: yes, this was one of the possible solutions to the problem, but there was already too much code written on the project, and it would have taken too much efforts to use the bootstrap ui. thanks for the reply though :)